# How to tell apart base game and DLC scenarios in Gloomhaven?

Tags: gloomhaven

Some of the mercenaries' personal quests mention "base game", presumably as opposed to DLC content:
[image: Quest example]

But how do you tell if a given scenario is part of the base game when you didn't play the game before the DLC got introduced? For now I've gathered that the whole cultist/Roland quest line is part of the Jaws of the Lion DLC but for all I know there are other questlines that are also part of the DLC and that I haven't seen yet.

At first I thought "Core quest" meant base game but I think the Blood Tumor boss fight was also marked as such despite being part of the DLC so now I really don't have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Welp silly me just realized that this icon is in fact a lion's head :
[image]

So that seems to indicate DLC scenarios, while the ones with a "!" are core scenarios from the base game and the ones with a star/diamond are side scenarios from the base game.

Well maybe this will help another blind player some day in the future.